# Picture in picture mode in Android API level lower than 24

Tags: java, android, android-picture-in-picture

If picture in picture mode is not supported on Android API version lower than 24, then how does **whatsapp** use it (in API version lower than 24)? Is there any way to use Picture in picture mode playing in API lower than 24?